# Detect scrolling - scroll to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a site whereby when the user starts to scroll it automatically scrolls them (not jump) to a set position, so that content can be seen. The content is already there on the page I just dont want them to scroll to it so as soon as they start to move down the page it will help them by scrolling to a set point.

This is what I had so far but I got lost:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(body).scroll(function() {
    if ( $this).scrollTop() > 1 ) {

    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u4KQc/1/)

```
var scrollFunction = function() {
    $('html, body').not(':animated').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#layer-2").offset().top //gets the position of the next layer
    }, 1000, function() {
        $(document).off('scroll', scrollFunction)
    });
}

$(document).on('scroll', scrollFunction);
```

Comment: That's cute effect :p

Comment: @user2598957 I've updated the script. When the animation is finished, it enables scrolling. Its up to you to then check if the scroll position is at 0, to reattach the listener.

Comment: That's a pretty smart solution :D +1!

Answer (score 2):

You can bind your element with **scrollstart**  (also there is a **scrollstop**) event:

```
jQuery('#yourElementId').bind("scrollstart",scrollFunc);

var scrollFunc = function(){
  //if(jQuery('#yourElementId').scrollTop()>1) //unnecessary 
  jQuery('#yourElementId').scrollTop(300); // change 300 to any number you want
}
```

Comment: You've linked to "docs" for jQuery mobile, I don't think the OP's issue is mobile only. Scrollstart does not exist in jQuery, you need the plugin: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/special-scroll-events-for-jquery/